# Problema com return voltando null para outra classe

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe responsável por baixar uma lista de alunos em um web service através de um método onde passo como parâmetro uma string com o Código do professor e ele me retorna um Array de alunos. O problema é que quando chamo esse método na outra classe ele esta me retornando um array vazio.

Já fiz o debug no return do método do web service e ele está com todos os dados, so que quando recebo ele em outra classe ele está vazio.

Segue o codigo:

CLASSE WEBSERVICE COM O METODO QUE RETORNA OS ALUNOS

```
    ArrayList<Aluno> listAlunos = new ArrayList<>();



public ArrayList<Aluno> alunos(String codProfessor){


    try {
        SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        resposta.addProperty("CodigoPro", codProfessor);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultado);

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
            JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            aluno.setMatriculaAluno(jsonObject.getString("Matricula"));
            aluno.setNomeAluno(jsonObject.getString("Nome"));
            aluno.setDisciplinaAluno(jsonObject.getString("CodMat"));
            aluno.setTurmaAluno(jsonObject.getString("CodTur"));

          listAlunos.add(i,aluno); 
        }


    }  catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        soapFault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listAlunos; // FOI REALIZADO O DEBUG DESSA LINHA, ESTÁ OK COM TODOS OS DADOS
}
```

CLASSE ONDE CHAMO O METODO PARA QUE QUANDO A ACTIVITY FOR CRIADA ELE FAÇA RECUPERA ESSA LISTA DE ALUNOS E PASSA PARA A CLASSE DAO.

```
  AlunoDAO alunoDAO = new AlunoDAO(getBaseContext());
ArrayList<Aluno> listaAlunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
AlunoWS alunoWS = new AlunoWS();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    String nomeProfessor = getIntent().getStringExtra("Professor");

     baixarDados(nomeProfessor);

}


public void baixarDados(final String codProfessor){
    String msg = "Atualizando dados";
    String titulo = "Aguarde";

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                listaAlunos = alunoWS.alunos(codProfessor); //LISTA ALUNOS ESTÁ RECEBENDO NULL
                alunoDAO.insereAlunos(listaAlunos);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }).start();


}
```

Comment: Não há necessidade de você indicar o índice que será adicionado o objeto: `listAlunos.add(i,aluno);` ->  `listAlunos.add(aluno);`

Comment: E também definir o tipo de objeto que será implementado na interface da lista, na 1ª classe está assim: `ArrayList<Aluno> listAlunos = new ArrayList<>();` e Na segunda está assim `ArrayList<Aluno> listAlunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();`

Comment: Olha só, você está rodando o método dentro de uma thread, mas nesse caso você deveria ter algo síncrono já que você depende do retorno do seu webservice. Tenta tirar da thread só para testar. Se funcionar, aí você coloca dentro de uma AsyncTask, mas isso no webservice e não na activity.